# Regular Expression, comma must follow 1 or 2 digits numeric

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that ensure if there's a comma then the following text should be 1 or 2 digits numeric.

Here's what I have so far.

```
(^\d{0,2})+(,\d{0,2})*$
```

The works in most cases but it is considering the following as valid.

```
12,22,,,,,,,,,, and 12,22,,,,,,,,,,12,12
```

What did I do wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: Well, `\d{0,2}` means zero, one, or two digits...

Answer (score 6):

`\d{0,2}` means "between 0 and 2 digits". It should be `\d{1,2}`

Comment: duh!  Thank you every much

Answer (score 4):

You are matching 0 to 2 digits after the comma instead of 1 or 2 
the following should do the trick

```
(^\d{1,2})+(,\d{1,2})*$
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a negative look-ahead to assert that there aren't 3 digits after a comma, and keep the main regex simply "all commas or digits"

```
^(?!.*,\d{3})[,\d]+$
```